# why would mysql_connect randomly not work?

Tags: php, mysql-connect

I have mysql_connect running with no problem on my site...

I have a script that i'm running from a CRON job, and here it decides to not work, and output these two errors:

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /home/mysite/public_html/phpMySQLAutoBackup/files/schema_for_export.php on line 22
```

Yes, I'm using [phpMySQLAutoBackup](http://www.dwalker.co.uk/phpmysqlautobackup/)

Any ideas?  This befuddles me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [PHP Errors on a cronjob, works fine at prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826552/php-errors-on-a-cronjob-works-fine-at-prompt)

Check your $PATH, permissions, & any environment variables...

Answer (score 2):

The time I got one of these (Unable to load dynamic library ...) I was missing a module. In your case my guess would be that you're missing "libssh2"